Is there way to enter id without asking user
How do I write my query for a new user through HTML login so that id is there and no column mismatch?
I skip id and wrote all values like username, email etc. But not id as it was autoincrement. How do I get increment in id as I cannot ask from user to enter id?

It is unclear exactly what you're stuck on. Is it inserting, then don't include the ID column in your insert statement (if the ID columns is autoincrement). If it is about obtaining the generated id after insert, then you need to use the getGeneratedKeys() facility of JDBC.

For MySQL, you can get the id that was last generated over a database connection by using the native function
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();

EDIT per Mark Rotteveel's suggestion
But if you are using JDBC, the correct database agnostic way would be to use the inbuilt features of Statement
int id = 0;
String query = "INSERT INTO mytable (username, email, etc) values (?, ?, ?)";

// create a PreparedStatement object
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

// set the query paramaters
ps.setString(1, username);
ps.setString(2, email);
ps.setString(3, etc);

// execute the query
ps.executeUpdate();

// retrieve the generated keys
ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs.next()) {
  id = rs.getInt(1);
} 
return id; 

